# How can I override FOSUserBundle autorization in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOSUserBundle and i'm looking for the best way to add some autorization logic.

The routes i want to securize always starts with the same pattern :

```
/admin/{id}/
```

The ID refers to an entity "Site".
The User class has a ManyToOne relation with this entity.

So, i want to check each time if the route called is corresponding to the "Site" stored in my user instance.
I checked the documentation to find the best way : creating different roles, using ACL, check manually in each controlers... I don't want to check in each function called but i don't find a easier method, so i'm looking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found another solution. I'm not sure if it's the best way but it works.

All my controllers extend an abstract controller with a function __call that check if the session user's website  is corresponding to the one passed by the param converter. I change all my controller method vibilility to "protected", and it seems to be good.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the route authorization acces into the `app/config/security.yml` file

Like this :

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/*, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: It's what i did, but it's not checking the ID like i explained.